# React ask if jwt valid for redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to prevent the user from accessing a certain page, this doesn't work because the time it takes for the request to complete the render default already exported.
how can i do to redirect my user only after the request

```
function request() {
    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                isAuthenticated = true;

            } else {
                isAuthenticated = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
}

request();

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (

    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/login'/>
    )}/>
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I use my route here

```
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={home} />
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={login} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/admin" exact component={admin} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/generatekey" exact component={generatekey} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" exact component={userlist} />
                    <Route component={error_page} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

in the component route where is called on top of App

Comment: Maybe render by default the page for unauthorized users and when the response received you can navigate to the wanted page

Comment: the default page for unauthorized is the login page, and this function is called every time an user switch between private page

Comment: Please format your code, help us help you

Answer (score 1):

What I think you should do is:

1. [Lift the `isAuthenticated` state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass it to the private routes
2. By default the `isAuthenticated` state will equal `false`

```js
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
```

3. On login you will call `setIsAuthenticated` with `true`
4. All the private routes are now re-rendered with the updated `isAuthenticated`
5. On logout call `setIsAuthenticated` with `false`

Answer (score 0):

From the file where you are using route you can declare useState and Change isAuthenticated accordingly

```
const App = ()=>{
const [isAuthenticated,setisAuthenticated] = useState(false) 
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(()=>{
function request() {
axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setisAuthenticated(true)
            setLoading(false)
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

request();
 },[])
return (<BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={home} />
                <Route path="/login" exact component={login} />
                {!loading&&
                 <>
                <PrivateRoute path="/admin" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} exact component={admin} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/generatekey" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} exact component={generatekey} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} exact component={userlist} />
                 </>
                }
                <Route component={error_page} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>)}
```

You can change your login route to and call setisAuthenticated after login or you can call your function to check for login whenever and change isAuthenticated there

```
<Route path="/login" render={()=><login
setisAuthenticated={setisAuthenticated}/>} ></Route>
```

In your PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component,isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => {(

return (<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
isAuthenticated === true
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to='/login'/>
)}/>)
)}
```

Comment: The convention for the name of the set function coming from `useState` is `set<state-name>‘

Comment: I got this error  "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
PrivateRoute@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:451:23"

Comment: Can I see how you're using PrivateRoute? You might want to move the request function to where you're importing PrivateRoute and set the state there and pass the state into PrivateRoute

Comment: you want to declare authenticated outside of your PrivateRoute component and pass the state into PrivateRoute

Comment: So exactly as I suggested 

Comment: any example of how i can do ?

Comment: {!this.props.isLoading &&
                        <PrivateRoute path="/admin" exact component={admin}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path="/generatekey" exact component={generatekey} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" exact component={userlist} />
                    } 

 so I tried this and it doesn't work `Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?`

Comment: I used this.props because I got a special routing component

Comment: add <> </> in-between the privateroutes

Comment: Ok it almost work, when I login now it return me to the 404 page. [Here](https://pastebin.com/xa4ka1P3) is my whole code